# Large json file transformation via code or not

Tags: java, c++, json, large-files, jsoniq

after trying to work with mongoDB , and finding out that it dosn't work with documents that are larger the 16 mega .
i need to find way to load large complex json file ( i guess to memory ) .
and to transform it to my need via ( i guess ) Query processor like jsoniq , but i open to other solutions .
the key here that i dont what to change the master json . and i don't care which programming language
 to make it ,
 but i just want to find method to do it right and fast.

Comment: How did you get 3000+ points with horrible questions like this?

Comment: i dont know , what i do know i can't find simple answer to simple question , just asking from frustration

Comment: Did you try [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)?

Comment: wow this is great lib! thanks @Moritz Petersen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Jackson library can help you. Its official website states the following features:

Jackson is a:

1) Streaming (reading, writing)

2) FAST (measured to be faster than any other Java json parser and data binder)

3) Powerful (full data binding for common JDK classes as well as any Java bean class, Collection, Map or Enum)

4) Zero-dependency (does not rely on other packages beyond JDK)

5)Open Source (LGPL or AL)

6) Fully conformant

7) Extremely configurable

JSON processor (JSON parser + JSON generator) written in Java. Beyond basic JSON reading/writing (parsing, generating), it also offers full node-based Tree Model, as well as full OJM (Object/Json Mapper) data binding functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Zorba can also help for this kind of use case.

It is a open-source memory engine that supports XQuery and JSONiq. It can consume all kind of input including JSON from the local filesystem, from the Web or from other sources.

It is commonly used on the command line, but since it is open-source (C++), it can also be adapted and integrated in other environments.

For completeness, other JSONiq implementations are available, such as Xidel. Finally, XQuery was extended in its version 3.1 to support JSON as well, so that many XQuery engines (Saxon, ...) also qualify for manipulating JSON.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13475560)

Comment: Thanks Lal! Very good point. I have made the answer more verbose and removed the link.